# Dynamic sorting in related lists in Salesforce classic

Tags: related-list, sort

It seems I can't change the sorting order of a related lists inside the Account layout.

Is it possible to allow the user to change the sorting column of a related list without "going to list" ?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to sort a related list is by setting the related sort options in the related lest settings on the page layout interface.